# XSL is not working under IE

Tags: xml, client-side, xslt

I have the following xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:param name="currentPage">Buildings</xsl:param>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="site/page[@id=$currentPage]"/>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="site/page[@id='Buildings']">
        <ul id="ulSlideshow" class="thumbs noscript">
            test
        </ul>   
    </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is working good under Chrome and Firefox, but it is not working under IE. I'm using [jQuery.transform.js](http://daersystems.com/jquerytransform.asp) plugin in the version for client-side transformation. Here is the code that is used to call the plugin.

```
$("#information").transform({
                    xml:"pages.xml",
                    xsl:currentPage             
                });
```

What is the reason it is not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `windows-1251`??

Windows-1251 is an 8-bit character encoding for languages using the Cyrillic alphabet (Russian, Serbian, etc.). Is that the encoding that you need??

I think the problem is that IE is using the encoding in the response header. Try adding this meta tag to the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Try adding the following to the XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" standalone="yes" encoding="windows-1251" />
```

Comment: Do you have any issues with other encodings, or does it seem to be specific to windows-1251?

Comment: I have tried with UTF-8 as you suggested, but it is the same result.